# list of files in a directory

Tags: linux, unix

I'm looking for a way to list the first 100 files (by created date) in a directory without having to first do a full listing of the directory and then piping it to another utility to truncate the results. The reason being that there a LOT of files in the directory.

Running (ls -l | head -n 100) takes too long to complete the first part. I'd like to quit once I get the first 100 without having to read full directory contents.

Is this possible to do in RHE Linux?

Comment: Do you need the `-l` - because `ls -1f` will be much faster because it doesn't need to sort or stat.

Comment: I just need to grab the file names and process them from my java code. So you're right, I dont need the '-l'. Thanks.

Comment: How much files do you have in the directory? Is it possible to use subdirectories instead? Do you want to see the same 100 files when you make a new listing?

Comment: Edited. Sorry, I'm not seeing another option to reply - 'comment' or 'Answer your question' are the only two links I see.

Comment: how you can sort without knowing the full content? additionally, there are flaws to rely on `ls` to provide list of files(but mostly of the time you won't get caught).

Comment: Many file systems do not store directory entries in any particular order, so there will not be any shortcut to reading the entire list of directory entries (and possibly `stat`-ing each file if that's required for your expected sort order).

Comment: I'm expecting about 100k files in the directory at any point and I'm restricted to the same directory - can't do subdirs. My code will delete the first 100 files after processing - so the next time I shouldn't see the same files.  I guess there's no shortcut then - I have to do a full listing and then pick my 100, based on a couple of comments here.

Answer (score 1):

**find** seems to be slightly quicker than **ls**.  I was looking at a directory with a thousand empty files.

The **time** command is useful for ... you guessed it ... determining how long stuff takes.

```
time ls -l | head -n 100
real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.008s

time ls -1 |head -n 100
real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.006s

time find . -maxdepth 1 -type f |head -n 100
real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.005s
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are processing directory from a program and not the command line, the system calls to process directory, opendir, closedir and readdir should be used. It is straightforward to use these system calls from a C program. I think there is a way to use these calls from Java as well.